# How do you query using an index in the Architect Serverless Framework?

Tags: serverless, architect

I am trying to query using an index but keep getting this error:

`ValidationException: Query condition missed key schema element: trackID`

Here is my .arc file

```
@tables
skytracks
  trackID *String
  _ttl TTL

@indexes
skytracks
  skyTrackType *String
```

Here is the relevant piece of the http get handler:

```
const skyTrackType = req.queryStringParameters.skytracktype
const data = await arc.tables()
const trackingData = await data.skytracks.query({
      KeyConditionExpression: `skyTrackType = :skyTrackType`,
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':skyTrackType': skyTrackType
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

[Architect](https://arc.codes/) automatically names the index `attribute-index`

This needs to be added to the query in the question: `IndexName: 'skyTrackType-index'`

```
const trackingData = await data.skytracks.query({
      KeyConditionExpression: `skyTrackType = :skyTrackType`,
      IndexName: 'skyTrackType-index',
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':skyTrackType': skyTrackType
      }
    })
```

Comment: This was a little funky to figure out, glad I found your answer. Looks like their helper functionality arc.tables().data.tblName._name() doesn't work correctly yet with indexes. 

https://arc.codes/reference/functions/tables/node#data.name